# Issue after moving the ib_logfile1 and ib_logfile0 files

Tags: mysql, database

I wanted to increase the `innodb_log_file_size` for better performance. And i increased it from the default value to 256 MB. As usual i got the error saying `InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes`. So i moved these files to different location and restarted the mysql server. It worked. Before shuting down the mysql server i also made `innodb_fast_shutdown  =  0`.

But i have a doubt, after mysql shutdown can we expect mysql is an consistent state and all the data that were in the `ib_logfile0`  and `ib_logfile1` have been written to data files. So that i can delete these files or should i do something else also.

And if the answer is mysql will be in consistant state than why these files contain some data even after graceful shutdown and start up with `innodb_fast_shutdown  =  0`.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps I followed:

1. `SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0`
2. `/etc/init.d/mysqld stop`
3. `rm -f /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0`
4. `rm -f /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1`
5. `/etc/init.d/mysqld start`

these steps are correct and is accepted by [RolandoMySQLDBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877/rolandomysqldba) in this [thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41542/issue-after-moving-the-ib-logfile1-and-ib-logfile0-files).