# Issues with ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1

Tags: mysql, wamp

Since I last re-installed WAMP I've been having issues with **ib_logfile0** and **ib_logfile1**.

Whenever I restart my computer, the MySQL part of WAMP refuse to start and the only way to fix this is to remove those two files (I found that "solution" here on stackoverflow, but I have also read that you shouldn't delete them, but it seems to do the trick, no data lost.), restarting WAMP works fine, but not when restarting computer.

Both **ib_logfile0** and **ib_logfile1** are 49152kb in size (if that matters).
And i have **NOT** tried to change **innodb_log_file_size**

Even though MySQL log is enabled, the logfile is empty, so can't figure out the problem that way.

Anyone has a clue about what's wrong? and how to fix it? (so that i don't have to delete the files every time i start WAMP)

*(possibly a related issue --> [Issue after moving the ib_logfile1 and ib_logfile0 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384009/issue-after-moving-the-ib-logfile1-and-ib-logfile0-files) but i'm not sure what to make of it.)*

Comment: If MySQL fails to start then there must either be a `mysql error log` or look in the `Windows Event Viewer` for error messages from MySQL.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any logs regarding MySQL, and I'm not sure where to look in the Event Viewer and \wamp\logs\mysql.log is empty.

Comment: When you say you installed WAMP do you mean WAMPServer or XAMPP or did you do it all manually

Comment: I installed WAMPServer from http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper and I downloaded the 64-bit - Apache: 2.4.9 MySQL: 5.6.17 - PHP: 5.5.12 - PHPMyAdmin: 4.1.14 - SqlBuddy: 1.3.3 - XDebug: 2.2.5

Comment: I have an idea that i'm going to try though, i'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems the problem has been fixed, still not sure WHY it happened.

To fix the problem I first exported all necessary databases, then i deleted all the files from the MySQL\Data\ folder except for the standard/default files that comes with a fresh WAMP install.

(default files being; **auto.cnf**, **performance_schema** (folder) and **mysql** (folder))

Then i just re-opened phpmyadmin and re-created all databases and imported all the database files (structure and data).

By doing all this, I got rid of ALOT of ib_logfiles and mysql-bin files (files like these https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDLmC.jpg) and the problem is now solved.

My knowledge of MySQL/ib_logfiles are somewhat limited, so I don't know why all these files were there, and why they caused the problem they did, but I'm glad it's fixed.